# Azure Node: Access table storage from SQL Azure Easy tables insert function

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-table-storage

I'm trying to insert some data into table storage from the SQL Azure EasyTables insert statement but context.execute() is being called before the table is created in table storage which stops my connection even though the code to create a new table is placed before context.execute(). Could some one tell me how I could stall the context.execute function until I finish my table storage set up. Below is my code. Thanks for the help

```
    table.insert(function (context) {
    var azure = require('azure-storage');  
    var tableService = azure.createTableService('NAME', 'KEY');

    context.user.getIdentity().then((data) => {
        tableService.createTableIfNotExists('UserInfo', function(error, result) { 
            if (error) { 
                //do something
            }else {

                var entGen = azure.TableUtilities.entityGenerator;
                var task = {
                  PartitionKey: entGen.String(context.user.id),
                  RowKey: entGen.String('1'), 
                  name : entGen.String(data.facebook.claims.name), 
                  email : entGen.String(data.facebook.claims.emailaddress),
                  createdOn: entGen.DateTime(new Date(Date.UTC(2016, 3, 27))),
                };

                tableService.insertEntity('UserInfo',task, function (error, result, resp) {
                    if(!error){
                        //respond with success message
                    }else{
                        //respond with failure message
                    }
                });
            } 
        }); 
    });

      context.item.userId = context.user.id;
      return context.execute(); //This line is executed before I get success/failure response from table storage

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote the tableService.createTableIfNotExists(...); into a new function and then called the function from "use" operation

table.insert.use(insertMiddleware, table.operation);

Answer (score 0):

This is because `getIdentity()` returns a Promise object.

The code `then((data) => { ... })` will be executed after its being invoked successfully.

More details about how Promise.then() works, pls see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

You can write the code `tableService.createTableIfNotExists(...);` into a method and call the method in context.execute().

Comment: But Alex, shouldn't then((data) => { ... }) execute before the context.execute() method and I should still be able to create a table? or are you saying context.execute happens first then comes the then((data) => { ... })

Comment: I mean that when your code run to 'context.user.getIdentity()', the program will check if 'getIdentity()' throws an error, if not, the 'then((data) =>{...})' will be executed at once which insert a new Entity into the table. I think the 'context.execute()' is useless here. You can do like this: 1) move code tableService.createTableIfNotExists(...); into a method and call the method in context.execute(). or 2) remove 'context.execute()'.

Comment: Thanks Alex but if I remove the context.execute() which I tried previously, I get The item does not exist error. The method "insert" is expecting a return statement. and any return statement I place inplace of context. execute(), that statement executes again before the table creation so I'm back to square 1. I did fix my issue, see my answer below. The middleware "use" always executes before the table operation until I specify to move to table operation. so I moved all my code there